# Download google sheets file as csv to cpanel using cron task

Tags: google-sheets, cpanel, cron-task

I have a specific task to accomplish which involves downloading a file from Google sheets. I need to always have just one file downloaded so the new file will overwrite any previous one (if it exists)

I have tried the following command but I can't quite get it to work. Not sure what's missing.

/usr/local/bin/php -q https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11rFK_fQPgIcMdOTj6KNLrl7pNrwAnYhjp3nIrctPosg/ -o /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files.csv

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve with the following:

curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[...]/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%5B...%5D/edit?usp=sharing) --output /home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/file.csv